# Ajax & multiple sessions

Tags: ajax, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, session-state

Can any one tel me whether ajax calls lead for multiple sessions. In my application I can see more than 5 sessions are created for each user. (By monitoring the firewall). main web page in the Application sends five ajax calls to the webserver once a 30 seconds to retrieve data. 
Is there is any connection between ajax calls and multiple sessions? Can anyone pls explain.

Answer (score 3):

That's possible if it doesn't send the session cookie along in the request header. With [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) you can verify this.

In decent Ajax frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) this is already taken into account.

---

[image]

Comment: I'm new to J2EE stuff. Can you bit explain how can I overcome this problem. How can I send cookie information with Ajax calls? further information will be highly appriciated.. Thanks

Comment: As you told I tried with firebug and following are the cookie info I got from two requests. JSESSIONID=7F5118C2BD6E87AA996CEDF003FBBE39.public2; __utma=1.756902097.1295154851.1295154851.1295154851.1; __utmb=1.2.10.1295154851; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1295154851.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
***************JSESSIONID=7F5118C2BD6E87AA996CEDF003FBBE39.public2; __utma=1.756902097.1295154851.1295154851.1295154851.1; __utmb=1.2.10.1295154851; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1295154851.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)**** what can you say about this.. Thanks

Comment: If that's the same session ID as `${pageContext.session.id}` in the JSP page is telling and the ajax response didn't return a `Set-Cookie` header, then it's fine and the problem is caused by something else.